# Hover menu z-index IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, z-index

I have a very simple JavaScript and CSS hover menu setup apart of the menu on my website. It works great almost everywhere, *EXCEPT* - there is an issue with the z-index on IE8.

```
.rolloverMenu {
    background-color: #4A5508;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #AC4718;
    border-left: 1px solid #AC4718;
    border-right: 1px solid #AC4718;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #AC4718;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    padding: 10px 10px 6px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

It goes behind my content and doesn't stay on top of, as supposed to. I know theres different stacking rules in IE, so any suggestions??

*(Also have tried setting to* `z-index:9999;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the z-index to the div that your menu is hiding behind to a lower z-index than your menu.

Comment: it doesn't matter if it has lower or greater value.. it just needs to has a value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is: 
Add z-index to parent container (div, table, ul... etc).

Example:

```
<div class="menu_container">
  menu here..
</div>
<div class="other_content">
  other data here
</div>
```

The div.menu_container should have a z-index value to make its content goes over the other divs.

Comment: Thanks for the response! And to a lower z-index value, right?

Comment: i am not sure about what do you mean, but the container should have a z-index value.. no matter what it is. because in IE, the elements has default z-index values

Comment: I'm wondering in which stacking order should they be IE? The UL, Hover Div, and CSS rollover (above).